# How to install vim with +clientserver on debian?

Tags: clientserver, linux-debian

I would like to enable Vim's clientserver support for the [vimtex call back mechanism](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/doc/vimtex.txt#L253).

> "Vim requires |+clientserver| in order to allow inverse search from the PDF
> viewer to Vim (see |vimtex-synctex-inverse-search|)."

I installed the following apt packages:

```
sudo apt install vim
sudo apt install vim-nox
```

But I still have the following when I look at vim --version:

```
paul@castanea:~/rp/paulrougieux.github.io$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jun 15 2019 16:41:15)
Included patches: 1-875, 878, 884, 948, 1046, 1365-1368, 1382, 1401
Modified by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
[...]
-clientserver
```

I would like to enable the clientserver feature. Is that possible by installing an apt package on debian?

Answer (score 4):

As explained in [this 2004 bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=114358):

```
sudo apt install vim-gtk
```

Adds +clientserver support to vim.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled on this old thread and was not satisfied with the information provided so far, so I did a bit more research and posted a question on the Vim maintainer list for Debian. They were kind enough to get back to me and point me in the right direction.

The actual reason for this package dependency is that the client-server communication occurs through the X11 server.

See this section of the Vim manual:
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/remote.html#x11-clientserver

In case anyone else stumbles on this issue and is as confused as I was. I thought it used a Unix domain socket or something.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure if I understand whether your answer provides another solution to the problem or just additional information.